# How to convert Hour to 12 HRS / 24 HRS Format with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

i convert Hour to 12 HRS / 24 HRS Format this way in c# but not being able to do the same in javascript.

my c# code for formatting 12 HRS / 24 HRS Format as below

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
{
    strHrs.Add((i == 0 ? "00" : Convert.ToDateTime(TimeSpan.FromHours(i).ToString()).ToString("hh")),
        (i == 0 ? "00" : Convert.ToDateTime(TimeSpan.FromHours(i).ToString()).ToString("HH")));
}
```

i got a js code which looks fine

```
var timeString = "18:00:00";
var H = +timeString.substr(0, 2);
var h = H % 12 || 12;
var ampm = H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
timeString = h + timeString.substr(2, 3) + ampm;
```

i have to show 12 hrs format in dropdown text but have to show 24 hrs format in dropdown value.
but how to apply in my case not very sure. so any help would be appreciated. thanks

### EDIT

```
        function convertDateTo12Hrs(timeStr, is24) {
            if (is24) {
                var BigHrs = timeStr.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + timeStr : timeStr;
                return BigHrs; // return if is24 true
            }
            var h = "" + (+timeStr > 12 ? timeStr - 12 : timeStr);
            return h.length == 1 ? "0" + h : h;
        }
```

### Calling

```
convert("2", true); // "02"
convert("18", false); // "06"
```

Comment: in a for loop i need to populate a drop down with hour. drop down text will be 12 hrs format and value will be 24 hrs format.

Comment: Are you able to use external libraries? (momentJs?)

Comment: @Kyle : yes i am using momentJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your comment on my post, you could just create a function which would return both.

```
function convert(timeStr, is24) {
    if (is24) return timeStr; // return if is24 true
    var h = "" + (+timeStr  > 12 ? timeStr - 12 : timeStr);
    return h.length == 1 ? "0" + h : h;
}
```

Now you can call it like

```
convert("18", true); // "18"
convert("18", false); // "06"
```

Comment: i want to call like this way convert("18", true); // "18"
convert("18", false); // "06". i have no business with minute and sec. hour should be return in 2 digit like 06 or 12 etc. so please edit your code accordingly. thanks

Comment: give also js fiddle link if possible.

Comment: i just update ur code a bit because when hour length was 1 and need to return 24 hrs format then routine was returning single value instead of adding 0 as prefix. so i just edit that portion and update my answer. thanks